# Generate recovery key for Mac Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, recovery

I encrypted my Mac Time Machine recently, but have unable to figure out how to generate the 'recovery key' in the advent that I forget the password. Is there a simply way to do this on Mac like with Windows systems?